# Postfix + Dovecot fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms

Tags: linux, debian, ssl, postfix, dovecot

When I try to login via telnet I am getting kicked out immediately:

```
telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

In the logs I get the following error message:

```
Jul 17 23:15:26 mail postfix/smtpd[1606]: connect from localhost[::1]
Jul 17 23:15:26 mail postfix/smtpd[1606]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Jul 17 23:15:27 mail postfix/master[597]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 1606 exit status 1
Jul 17 23:15:27 mail postfix/master[597]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

I am getting the same error message too, when a MTA from outside wants to deliver a mail.

My 10-master.conf:

```
# Postfix smtp-auth
unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
mode = 0666

}
```

Auth seems to exist:

```
ls -l /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Jul 17 22:55 /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
```

And last but not least my postconf -n:

```
postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = XXX, localhost.XXX, localhost, $mydomain
myhostname = XXX
mynetworks_style = subnet
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_domains
relayhost = XXX
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport, $relay_domains
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_maps
```

Did I make a mistake somewhere? If not, how can I debug any further?

Thank you very much in advance (:

EDIT:

my 10-auth.conf:

```
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
auth_username_format = %Ln
auth_mechanisms = plain login
!include auth-ldap.conf.ext
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an auth_mechanisms line in your dovecot configuration?

If so, post it, if not that's probably the issue.

default for reference:
auth_mechanisms = plain login

But you're probably going to want something else because of your postfix sasl security options, both plaintext and login are considered plaintext.

More: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/Mechanisms

Comment: Hi,

first of all, thank you very much for your reply.
So if I understand you correct, the problem is, that my sasl security options in postifx do not work together with my auth_mechanisms in dovecot?
I do not understand, where the problem lies, though. As far as I understood the options:
    
    smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
    smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous

should forbid plain text without TLS but allow it with TLS?!

Comment: Do you have a source for this assertion, it's not mentioned that TLS bypasses the noplaintext option in the official postfix documentation.

Comment: Also you may want to remove the security options line and allow plaintext and use smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt to require TLS.

Comment: My source is: http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html
"A more sophisticated policy allows plaintext mechanisms, but only over a TLS-encrypted connection:

    /etc/postfix/main.cf:
        smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
        smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous

But maybe I understood something wrong.

My goal is, not so send any plaintext login information as long as the connection is not secured. I have to use plaintext though, since I am authenticating against an AD/samba4 server.

Comment: Not to send or not to allow to receive, almost all of these configuration options deal with clients connecting to postfix, not as far as i know,  with postfix connecting out.

Comment: @AaronTate `smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt` works for me, thanks!!!